# SO live refresh system off

Tags: support, notifications, live-refresh, notification-bar

If this has already been discussed or this is not the right place to ask let me know and I will delete this question.

That being said, the first two months of me using SO, the push notification system(reputation changes, comments, live tracking of votes and answer acceptance) was flawless.

However, in the past month, I notice up and again that it is clearly off.
For example, I will be in a question tab and post an answer and monitor that question only to realize there have been alot of changes on this page such as votes and new answers and comments. However, to get those updates I have to keep refreshing the page. What is more peculiar is I can glimpse reputation changes for that question in another tab being updated correctly, but not for the post itself.

What gives?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, for me its more than just reputation changes. Its the whole deal. I cant see voting taking place or comments or new answers. The sockets seem to be completely blocked

Comment: It's all the same source, sockets - so same bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard "This question has been asked before **and already has an answer**": the linked question has zero answers.

Comment: ShadowWizard didn't write the close reason. A question is a dupe (essentially) if the duped question can also provide answers fit for the duplicate one. On the other question, comment, upvote, answer if you have more ideas to add, and you can add a bounty to draw attention. Having more than one question for the same bug/feature-request means "attention" (answers, votes, ideas) is split, instead of concentrated in one question.

Comment: Agree with @James. I see no reason the discussion be in two separate questions.

Comment: @James, then they need to remove the **and already has an answer** part from the duplicate definition

Comment: @James, also, recurrent questions with no answers stress the importance of the issue. We cannot depend on old unanswered questions, they will simply be forgotten. Also, frankly, I dont have much meta points to assign a bounty

Comment: @AmmarCSE I don't disagree. That would need a new feature-request. Feel free :)

Comment: @James I know ShadowWizard did it well and it isn't his fault. I agree it is better if we have just 1 question to focus on, but the gray line should be defined at some point if a question remains unanswered.

Comment: Now asked: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261270/duplicates-of-unanswered-questions.

Comment: Just for the record, when I stated "needs a new feature request" I meant the fact close reasons states "other answers" even if there is none in the duped question